# ¿Cómo hacer listas dependientes con Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, blade

Tengo la necesidad de listar, en una vista de blade, los "destinos" pertenecientes a un país; pero listando varios países con sus respectivos "destinos".

Tengo las tablas "paises" y "destinos" relacionadas a través del campo idPais.

Lo que he intentado hasta el momento es lo siguiente:

### Controlador

```
public function activatedDestinations(){

    $paises = Pais::where('estatus','=', 1)->get();
    $destinos = Destination::where('idPais','=', $paises->idPais)->where('estatus','=', 1)->get();

    return view('destinations', compact('paises', 'destinos'));
}
```

### Modelo Pais

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pais extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'pais';
   protected $primaryKey = 'idPais';
   public $timestamps = false;

   protected $fillable = [
    'idPais',
    'pais'
   ];
}
```

### Modelo Destino

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Destination extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'destino';
   protected $primaryKey = 'idDestino';
   public $timestamps = false;

   protected $fillable = [
    'iPais',
    'destino',
    'slug',
    'imagen',
    'estatus'
   ];
}
```

### RESPUESTA OBTENIDA EN LOCALHOST:8000/DESTINATIONS/

```
**Property [idPais] does not exist on this collection instance.**
```

### Lo que pretendo hacer en la vista es lo siguiente:

- Pais 1
  -- Destino 1
  -- Destino 2
  -- Destino N
- Pais 2
  -- Destino 1
  -- Destino 2
  -- Destino N

...

Comment: Muestra el código de la vista para ver cómo intentas recorrer la data

Comment: El tema está en el Controller, aun no intento pintar los datos en la vista por que aun no llegan.

La verdad es que seguro estoy que el tema está en recorrer cada país para consultar los destinos por país y armar un array manualmente o algo por el estilo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes manejar directamente con relaciones a través de Eloquent. Definiendo tus relaciones `hasMany` y `belongsTo`

**Destino**

Añade la relación `belongsTo` *o pertenece a*, es decir mediante un destino saber a que País pertenece.

```
public function pais()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Pais', 'idPais');
}
```

**Pais**

Añade la relación `hasMany` para relación de 1 a muchos, es decir un país puede tener 1 o muchos destinos

```
public function destinos()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Destino','idPais');
}
```

Para obtener  desde el controlador sería simplemente, utilizando [Eager Loads (with)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) para cargar la relación `destinos` a cada país obtenido, además recuerde que el segundo parámetro del `where`, cuando es una igualdad se puede obviar.

```
$paises = App\Pais::where('estatus', 1)->with(['destinos'=>function($query){
    // le decimos que cargue los destinos del país siempre y cuando el status sea 1
    return $query->where('estatus',1);
}])->get();

return view('destinations', compact('paises'));
```

Desde la Vista para iterar el resultado , sería *(la forma de mostrar los datos se puede personalizar)* .

```
@foreach ($paises as $paisItem)
    <h4>Pais  {{ $paisItem->pais}}</h4>
    @foreach ($paisItem->destinos as $itemDestino)
        <p> {{ $itemDestino->destino }}</p>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Genial!! Creo que es la mejor solución.

Answer (score 1):

Les comparto una solución que me parece puede no ser la más óptima pero me resolvió el problema.

### Controller

```
public function activatedDestinations(){
  $paises = Pais::where('estatus','=', 1)->get();
  $destinos = Destination::where('estatus','=', 1)->get();

  return view('destinations', compact('paises', 'destinos'));
}
```

### Vista

```
@foreach($paises as $pais)
  <h3>{{ $pais->pais }}</h3>

  <div class="row">
    @foreach($destinos as $destino)
      @if($pais->idPais == $destino->idPais)

        <div class="col s12 m4">
           <div class="card">
              <div class="card-image">
                 <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/334x251">
                 <a href="/deals/{{ $destino->slug }}">
                   <span class="card-title">{{ $destino->destino }}</span>
                 </a>
              </div>
           </div>
         </div>

      @endif
    @endforeach
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Agradecería mucho sus comentarios y posibles mejores soluciones con el tema.

Answer (score 0):

hay una forma donde se puede mostrar los países con su respectivo destino con el uso de with 
que corresponde el tema https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

```
$paises = Pais::where('estatus','=', 1)->with('iPais_all')->get();
```

en el modelo de Pais coloque la siguiente función

```
public function iPais_all(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Destination', 'idPais');
}
```

en la vista

```
@foreach($paises as $list)
    //imprimir los datos de pais
    @foreach($list->iPais_all as $destino)
     //imprimer los datos de destinos
     {{ $destino->destino }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu solución!!!